# How to extract specific element from htmlcollection

Tags: javascript

I made basic `html` dropdown with following code

```
<select id="logged_headerdropdown">
    <option>Choose Product</option>

    <option value="Add Product" label="Add Product">Add Product</option>

    <option value="Oranges" label="Oranges">Oranges</option>

    <option value="Tomatoes" label="Tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
</select>
```

And then I applied `flat-ui` style.I added [URL](http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/) for reference

```
<div class="col-md-21 col-sm-10 summaryHeaderLabel" id="joy_second" data-intro="2. Choose a quality deterioration model" data-position="bottom">
            <div class="row" id="headerdropdown_wrapper" data-pattern="currentSelect">
                <select name="primary" class="select-block max " id="logged_headerdropdown" style="display: none;">
    <option>Choose Product</option>

    <option value="Add Product" label="Add Product">Add Product</option>

    <option value="Oranges" label="Oranges">Oranges</option>

    <option value="Tomatoes" label="Tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>

</select><div class="btn-group select select-block max"><button class="btn dropdown-toggle clearfix btn-primary" data-toggle="dropdown" id="logged_headerdropdown"><span class="filter-option pull-left">Choose Product</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></button><span class="dropdown-arrow dropdown-arrow-primary"></span><ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-primary" role="menu" style="max-height: 220px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 0px;"><li rel="0" class="selected"><a tabindex="-1" href="#" class=""><span class="pull-left">Choose Product</span></a></li><li rel="1"><a tabindex="-1" href="#" class=""><span class="pull-left">Add Product</span></a></li><li rel="2"><a tabindex="-1" href="#" class=""><span class="pull-left">Oranges</span></a></li><li rel="3"><a tabindex="-1" href="#" class=""><span class="pull-left">Tomatoes</span></a></li></ul></div>                                        
            </div>

            <span class="label label-primary hide" id="summaryHeaderLabel"></span>

        </div>
```

After apply style to the dropdown,I am not able to access the first element with has tagName `a`.

While I try to extract all the elements(which elements has tagName `a`),I am getting list in `htmlcollection` format.From that format,I can't able to extract the second element from list.

Regarding this,I goggled it finally I find `htmlcollection` not extracted from `Array`,so it won't support `Array` corresponding functions.

How can I fix this.can anyone help me.

Comment: Try: `toArray=Array.call.bind([].slice);toArray(collection)`

Comment: Do you have three, or more, of those elements?

Comment: When you type it in the console the document is ready, if it's not working when included in the file, you probably included the script before the elements you're trying to access.

Comment: @DavidThomas `htmlcollection` has 24 elements.

Comment: There should be [no problems with this](http://jsfiddle.net/9AXmZ/), please show more code.

Comment: @Teemu I updated question with code,so can you look once.